# Bind scroll event to select element using angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am new to angularjs. And i dont know how to bind scroll event to the html element `select`.this is my directive to adding scrolling functionality.

```
myApp.directive('scrolly', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var raw = element[0];
            console.log(element[0]);
            element.bind('scroll', function () {
                console.log('inside scroll');
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Here I attached my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/8215/) link.Please someone help me to fix this issue.

Answer (score 1):

There is no HTML event fired when you scroll through a select box as it is rendered by your operating system and not the browser.

If you really need to catch this behavior, you should use a HTML select element, such as the popular [select2](https://select2.github.io/examples.html) or [selectize](http://selectize.github.io/selectize.js/) libraries.